# generating string from exited characters

Tags: c#, java

I have a character array as shown below :

```
char[] pwdCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFG" +
            "HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",<" + 
            ".>/?".ToCharArray();
```

and from this char array, i want to generate a string of minimum length 7 and all the characters in the string should be from the above char array.
How to do this operation?

Comment: What on earth is exited?  I see it a lot on here, and have never worked it out...

Comment: @ck Maybe it's a perverse deformation of "entered" :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate 7 random numbers between 0 and yourArray.length -1.
Pick the corresponding char in the array and put it in your final String.

Here is the code with a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Randdom();
for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    sb.append(pwdCharArray[random.nextInt(0, pwdCharArray.length -1)]);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

What's the maximum length? (You may want to parameterize the methods below to specify a minimum and maximum length.) Here's a simple way of doing it for exactly 7 characters:

Here's the C# version:

```
public string GeneratePassword(Random rng)
{
    char[] chars = new char[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = pwdCharArray[rng.Next(pwdCharArray.Length)];
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Note that the `Random` instance should be passed in to avoid the common problem of creating many instances of `Random`. I have an [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) describing this problem and ways around it. In essence, you should use one instance of `Random` per thread - don't create a new instance every time you want to use one, and don't reuse the same instance across multiple threads.

In fact, for a genuine password which is guarding sensitive information, you probably shouldn't be using `Random` at all, but rather something like [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) (or less directly, the results of [`RandomNumberGenerator.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ae535c8.aspx)). This can be somewhat harder to use, but will give you much more secure random numbers.

In Java it would be pretty similar, but then I'd use [`SecureRandom`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (which is fortunately rather easier to use than its .NET counterpart). In this case, you *can* create a new instance each time:

```
public String generatePassword() {
    char[] chars = new char[7];
    SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = pwdCharArray[nextInt(pwdCharArray.length)];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it starts with an `a`  - maybe `aa` or `ab`... am I close? ;p

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, I spotted that while I was doing the Java version :)

Comment: There's some joke here involving luggage combinations (and planetary shields), but I wouldn't stoop so low...

Answer (score 1):

(C# example)

```
Random rand = new Random();
char[] arr = new char[rand.Next(7,15)];
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) {
    arr[i] = pwdCharArray[rand.Next(pwdCharArray.Length)];
}
string pwd = new string(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Java, with variable length of the word, and test of working:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomWord {

    // Valid characters
    private static String VALID_CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFG" +
            "HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",<.>/?";

    // Minimal length thw word can have
    private static int MIN_LENGTH = 7;
    // Maximal length will be MIN_LENGTH + THRESHOLD - 1
    private static int THRESHOLD = 10;

    // Generate a random number generator.
    // The time in millis is used as seed prevents the numbers to be always the same in same order
    Random randomGenerator =  new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public String generateWord () {
        // Actual length of the word (from MIN_LENGTH to MIN_LENGTH + THRESHOLD - 1)
        int length = MIN_LENGTH + randomGenerator.nextInt(THRESHOLD);
        // Loop for every character
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // Appends one more random char
            word.append(VALID_CHARACTERS.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(VALID_CHARACTERS.length())));
        }
        // Returns the random word
        return word.toString();
    }

    // Test the class
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // Instantiates and tests the class
        RandomWord randomWord = new RandomWord();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            String word = randomWord.generateWord();
            System.out.println(word + " (" + word.length() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```